# Uniform probability distribution of natural numbers.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

So I'm a probability pleb, so please bear with me if the question seems too trivial.

Say I have the set of all natural numbers, which is countably infinite. What is the probability of getting  a particular natural number, say 9, is all numbers have equal probablity?

So this is what confused me:
If probabilty p(i) =x, $\sum_{i=1}^n x $ = nx = $\infty$ (Much like the argument for additivity over continuous set)

If I say probabilty =
$0$, total probability would be $\sum_{i=1}^n 0 = 0$

Can I say that probability of getting each particular number is some value arbitrarily close to 0, but not equal to 0 (limit of $\frac{1}{n}$ as n tends to $\infty$)? Or is probability distribution not defined for this?

Comment: This is a well known conundrum.  There is no such thing as a probability measure on the natural numbers where each number has equal probability.

Comment: The probability distribution you are looking for is called [natural density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density). It is not countably additive, i.e. the probability of a countable sum is not equal to the sum of probabilities, it only works for finite sums. So although any one number, or any finite set of numbers, has probability zero there are sets with non-zero probability. Say, the probability to be even is $1/2$.

Comment: @Stephen So we can't even claim that each natural number has equal probability, but this value is infinitesimal?

Comment: Infinitesimal's are rather hard to make rigorous.  There is this thing called "non-standard analysis" that allows infinitesimals.  But it really doesn't help you do this kind of thing.

Comment: Bayesian analysts have this thing called an improper distribution, where they don't mind if the total probability is infinite.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith How to prove that it does not exist

Comment: @dodo By the argument given in the original post.